# vncserver exit status 98

Tags: fedora, vnc

I can not get `vncserver` to start after following 
 [How To Install and Configure VNC Remote Access for the GNOME Desktop on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-remote-access-for-the-gnome-desktop-on-centos-7).

I get to `sudo systemctl restart vncserver@:4.service` and receive the following error:

```
 Job for vncserver@:1.service failed because the control process exited
 with error code. See "systemctl  status vncserver@:1.service" and
 "journalctl  -xe" for details.

$ sudo systemctl status vncserver@:1.service:**

 ● vncserver@:1.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)    Loaded:
 loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:1.service; enabled; vendor
 preset: disabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat
 2018-06-09 05:37:57 HST; 2min 0s ago   Process: 4270
 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/runuser -l john -c /usr/bin/vncserver :1
 (code=exited, status=98)   Process: 4268 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c
 /usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1  /dev/null 2&1 || : (code=exited,
 status=0/SUCCESS)

 Jun 09 05:37:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Remote
 desktop service (VNC)... Jun 09 05:37:57 localhost.localdomain
 systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service: Control process exited, code=exited
 status=98 Jun 09 05:37:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to
 start Remote desktop service (VNC). Jun 09 05:37:57
 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service: Unit entered
 failed state. Jun 09 05:37:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]:
 vncserver@:1.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What does exit code=98 mean?

**Things I've Tried**

Remove /tmp lock files

```
sudo rm -rfv /tmp/.X11-unix
sudo rm .X0-lock .X1-lock
```

**Edit 1:** I tried the same steps on Centos 7 and it worked fine. I wonder if this has to do with SE Linux on Fedora? Any suggestions?

**Edit 2**: After further research, this appears to be a SE Linux issue and reported bug: [Job for vncserver@:1.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1577511). I have tried the suggested resolutions without success.

Comment: I have a sneaky suspicion that the 98 doesn't mean anything in particular.  It appears in a lot of "can't start vncserver" questions but nobody explains the value (and the causes are different.)

Comment: @JeffLearman What "causes" are you referring to? This might help me pinpoint what is going on.

Comment: I googled "vncserver exit status 98" and saw a number of articles, with different solutions and situations.  I didn't look deep, so maybe there was a common underlying cause, but original causes (situations) were different.  One possibility is server name incorrect.  Try starting vncserver without the name (just run `vncserver &`).  Use "ps" to see what vnc sessions are running, because you can't start one that's already running.  Also a possible issue about running it as root since /home/root doesn't exist but you're running it as `john`.  (Make sure /home/john exists.)